# How to set the font size depending on the screen size

Tags: android, android-fonts

I added in my values the font size for each screen size
for normal screen: `<dimen name="fontsize">22sp</dimen>`
for small screen: `<dimen name="fontsize">19sp</dimen>`
...

but when I have two normal screen sizes one xhdpi and the other hdpi I had to add another value folder:
for normal-xhdpi screen: `<dimen name="fontsize">22sp</dimen>`
for normal-hdpi screen: `<dimen name="fontsize">15sp</dimen>`

but I know that the sp unit differs depending on the screen dpi why I had this error and how can I have the needed fontsize on all the screens?

What I want to know is:

> sp
>        Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you
>   use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
>   both the screen density and user's preference.

So why isn't that working? I placed a folder of valuse for each screen size small, normal, large and xlarge and I thought that the sp will be changed depending on the dpi so no need to add the dpi.. but that's not working wy?

Answer (score 1):

use this utillity class:

```
com.cutompackage;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    /**
     * Utillity class which is changing font size of text view in app in order to fit to given dimensions
     * @author Darko
     *
     */
    public class FontFitTextView extends TextView {

        public FontFitTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            initialise();
        }

        public FontFitTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            initialise();
        }

        private void initialise() {
            mTestPaint = new Paint();
            mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());
            // max size defaults to the initially specified text size unless it is
            // too small
        }

        /*
         * Re size the font so the specified text fits in the text box assuming the
         * text box is the specified width.
         */
        private void refitText(String text, int textWidth) {
            if (textWidth <= 0)
                return;
            int targetWidth = textWidth - this.getPaddingLeft()
                    - this.getPaddingRight();
            float hi = 100;
            float lo = 2;
            final float threshold = 0.5f; // How close we have to be

            mTestPaint.set(this.getPaint());

            while ((hi - lo) > threshold) {
                float size = (hi + lo) / 2;
                mTestPaint.setTextSize(size);
                if (mTestPaint.measureText(text) >= targetWidth)
                    hi = size; // too big
                else
                    lo = size; // too small
            }
            // Use lo so that we undershoot rather than overshoot
            if (this.getTextSize() > lo) {
                this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lo);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = getMeasuredHeight();
            refitText(this.getText().toString(), parentWidth);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
                final int before, final int after) {
            refitText(text.toString(), this.getWidth());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            if (w != oldw) {
                refitText(this.getText().toString(), w);
            }
        }

        // Attributes
        private Paint mTestPaint;
    }
```

and then just set in xml like:

```
 <com.cutompackage.FontFitTextView
                android:id="@+id/headerText"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
```

EDIT:
it will automatically change font size to fit given dimension (height and width) of `TextView` now you just need to set dimensions properly.

hope it helps

Comment: it does a good work :) but I just can't use it in my app because I need to add it in my listview and depending on the size of the textview it takes the fontsize so I have some textviews that contain lots of words->really tiny fontsize and other that don't contain lots of words->big fontsize don't want that; but thank u very much it's a nice solution..

Comment: well you may add conditions, minimal and maximal font size like: if(this.getTextSize()>max) this.setTextSize(max);
if you know what I am doing